# Spring mvc mapping(J2EE)

Tags: spring-mvc, mapping

In servlets for mapping I use `@WebServlet("/path")`
It means, that I can write in form's action `"/path"` and button click would be handled by my servlet.
In spring mvc I map controller's method as

```
@RequestMapping("/path")
```

It means, that I must write in form's action `"/webAppName/path"` and button click would be handled by my method. But if name of my war file will be change, I must been change mapping on html/jsp. I think it very bad. 
Can You help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you are absolutely wrong. Secondly, what you have mentioned as war file name, is actually context path which even remotely has no relationship with the war name.

Context path is used by the server to refer the webapp running on it. It can be possible that there are multiple applications deployed on your server so, for server to figure out which request is related to which web application context path is required.

The context path of the web application, which is matched against the beginning of each request URI to select the appropriate web application for processing. All of the context paths within a particular Host must be unique. If you specify a context path of an empty string (""), you are defining the default web application for this Host, which will process all requests not assigned to other Contexts.

The value of this field must not be set except when statically defining a Context in server.xml, as it will be inferred from the filenames used for either the .xml context file or the docBase.

And moreover, it has nothing to do with the architecture of the application weather it be Spring MVC or Java Dyanamic Web Application the same thing applies.

Comment: Ok, I accept. But if my cotext path will change, I must change all my actions on jsp?

Comment: The reason why you don't hard code the context path. You can do ${pageContext.request.contextPath} so, you don't have to worry about changing context paths

Comment: And I want to know(for information) how can I hard code the context path in web.xml?

Comment: You don't web.xml does not has to know about the context path. Its taken care by the server. But if you are using eclipse you could assign your own context path by going project properties > web project settings > assign a new context path there